# Limit Graph API permissions to single user

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I have built an application that uses graph api to make calendar updates to a user.  However in the api requests I pass the user and it appears as though our entire organization is available, meaning if someone got the secret key and the user ids, they could make changes to any user.  This seems less secure that EWS that at least required me to provide a user password to update their calendar.  Is there a way on the Azure side to limit access the application has to just a single user so I can be sure I'm not exposing my entire organization AD to the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, any of these permissions when granted as application type will grant your client app access to all mailboxes

- Mail.Read
- Mail.ReadBasic
- Mail.ReadBasic.All
- Mail.ReadWrite
- Mail.Send
- MailboxSettings.Read
- MailboxSettings.ReadWrite
- Calendars.Read
- Calendars.ReadWrite
- Contacts.Read
- Contacts.ReadWrite

You can create an [Application Access Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access) to scope your app to only have permissions to specific mailboxes.